# Python, bs4: Tags in inspection are nowhere to be found when parsing

Tags: python, parsing, tags, beautifulsoup

I run into an unexpected problem, I am using Python 3.5 and BeautifulSoup.
I want to parse the following link:

```
url = 'https://www.leboncoin.fr/chaussures/627533472.htm?ca=16_s'
import requests, bs4
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()
DicoSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
```

I am interested in retrieving the link to the pictures that are in the offer.
When I inspect the html of the website I found that there are to be found under the tag div with class 'thumbnails', they are under tag span with class 'item_imagePic', they are img tags

However, when I select the div tag, the span tags are nowhere to be found:

```
div = DicoSoup.select("div.thumbnails")

div
Out[54]: 
[<div class="thumbnails" data-alt="Talons aiguilles Stéphane Kélian - 37.5">
 <ul>
 <li class="thumb selected trackable" data-info='{"event_name" :             "ad_view::photos", "event_type" : "click", "click_type" : "N", "event_s2" : "2"}' id="thumb_0"></li>
 <li class="thumb trackable" data-info='{"event_name" : "ad_view::photos", "event_type" : "click", "click_type" : "N", "event_s2" : "2"}' id="thumb_1">          </li>
 <li class="thumb trackable" data-info='{"event_name" : "ad_view::photos", "event_type" : "click", "click_type" : "N", "event_s2" : "2"}' id="thumb_2"></li>
 </ul>
 </div>]
```

When I inspect the html content, here is what I see:

```
<div class="thumbnails" data-alt="Talons aiguilles Stéphane Kélian - 37.5" style="width: 596px;">
                        <ul style="">

                                <li id="thumb_0" class="thumb selected trackable" data-info="{&quot;event_name&quot; : &quot;ad_view::photos&quot;, &quot;event_type&quot; : &quot;click&quot;, &quot;click_type&quot; : &quot;N&quot;, &quot;event_s2&quot; : &quot;2&quot;}"><span class="item_imagePic"><img src="//img0.leboncoin.fr/thumbs/d89/d89c778e852e4a175d5d1ba96b2ec9c220445732.jpg" alt="Talons aiguilles Stéphane Kélian - 37.5"></span></li>

                                <li id="thumb_1" class="thumb trackable" data-info="{&quot;event_name&quot; : &quot;ad_view::photos&quot;, &quot;event_type&quot; : &quot;click&quot;, &quot;click_type&quot; : &quot;N&quot;, &quot;event_s2&quot; : &quot;2&quot;}"><span class="item_imagePic"><img src="//img1.leboncoin.fr/thumbs/7d9/7d9b62d9efd2187472dc16ca2794be1bbaeb1370.jpg" alt="Talons aiguilles Stéphane Kélian - 37.5"></span></li>

                                <li id="thumb_2" class="thumb trackable" data-info="{&quot;event_name&quot; : &quot;ad_view::photos&quot;, &quot;event_type&quot; : &quot;click&quot;, &quot;click_type&quot; : &quot;N&quot;, &quot;event_s2&quot; : &quot;2&quot;}"><span class="item_imagePic"><img src="//img2.leboncoin.fr/thumbs/288/28865002bb34bad516574bd1e9b42d2a2bb928f2.jpg" alt="Talons aiguilles Stéphane Kélian - 37.5"></span></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

How is it possible?
What do I need to do to select them?

I have tried:

```
div = DicoSoup.select_one("div.thumbnails span.item_imagePic")
div = DicoSoup.select_one("div.thumbnails ul li span.item_imagePic")
div = DicoSoup.select("div.thumbnails ul li span.item_imagePic")
span = DicoSoup.find('span', {'class': 'item_imagePic'})
span = DicoSoup.find('span',id="thumb_0")
div = DicoSoup.select("div.thumbnails img")
div = DicoSoup.select("div.thumbnails span img")
div = DicoSoup.select("div.thumbnails ul li span.item_imagePic img")
```

They all return me objects of type 'NoneType'

Thanks,

Comment: When you inspect it in your browser yes with everything rendered, right click and choose view-source and then see what is there. In particular *<p class="item_photo">3 photos disponibles</p>*

Comment: The tags are not in the view-source, which is what I am parsing I guess

Comment: Aaaah ok it is in a different place in the view-source page. I should be able to get it from there. How is it possible though? That I see different tags in my browser and in the view-source page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented the thumbnails are dynamically generated using JS but you can get the script and parse the paths:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://www.leboncoin.fr/chaussures/627533472.htm?ca=16_s").content)

script = soup.select_one("div.thumbnails").find_next("script")
print(script.text.strip())
```

That gives you:

```
var images = new Array(), images_thumbs = new Array();
                        images_thumbs[0] = "//img0.leboncoin.fr/thumbs/d89/d89c778e852e4a175d5d1ba96b2ec9c220445732.jpg"; 
              images[0] = "//img0.leboncoin.fr/images/d89/d89c778e852e4a175d5d1ba96b2ec9c220445732.jpg";

                        images_thumbs[1] = "//img1.leboncoin.fr/thumbs/7d9/7d9b62d9efd2187472dc16ca2794be1bbaeb1370.jpg"; 
              images[1] = "//img1.leboncoin.fr/images/7d9/7d9b62d9efd2187472dc16ca2794be1bbaeb1370.jpg";

                        images_thumbs[2] = "//img2.leboncoin.fr/thumbs/288/28865002bb34bad516574bd1e9b42d2a2bb928f2.jpg"; 
              images[2] = "//img2.leboncoin.fr/images/288/28865002bb34bad516574bd1e9b42d2a2bb928f2.jpg";
```

To get the images links:

```
import re


soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://www.leboncoin.fr/chaussures/627533472.htm?ca=16_s").content)

script = soup.select_one("div.thumbnails").find_next("script").text

print(re.findall("images_thumbs\[\d+\]\s+=\s+\"(.*?)\";", script))
```

Or just splitlines and strip:

```
 [s.split("=", 1)[1].strip('"; ') for s in script.splitlines() if s.strip().startswith("images_thumbs")]
```

Both give you:

```
[u'//img0.leboncoin.fr/thumbs/d89/d89c778e852e4a175d5d1ba96b2ec9c220445732.jpg', u'//img1.leboncoin.fr/thumbs/7d9/7d9b62d9efd2187472dc16ca2794be1bbaeb1370.jpg', u'//img2.leboncoin.fr/thumbs/288/28865002bb34bad516574bd1e9b42d2a2bb928f2.jpg']
[u'//img0.leboncoin.fr/thumbs/d89/d89c778e852e4a175d5d1ba96b2ec9c220445732.jpg', u'//img1.leboncoin.fr/thumbs/7d9/7d9b62d9efd2187472dc16ca2794be1bbaeb1370.jpg', u'//img2.leboncoin.fr/thumbs/288/28865002bb34bad516574bd1e9b42d2a2bb928f2.jpg']
```

Last all you need is to prepend the scheme which is *https*:

```
 ["https://"+ path for path in re.findall("images_thumbs\[\d+\]\s+=\s+\"(.*?)\";", script)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: How can I make a list with the three images? - You answered before I could even ask the question ;)

Comment: @MthClv,  no worries, with https prepended you should be able to see the image when you click on the links.